# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04.1 with AMD RX480

Tags: drivers, sound, amd-graphics

After I changed my old R9 280 for my new RX480, I am unable to get sound via HDMI. Connecting a USB-bluetooth headset does play sound on it, though. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.1 and upgrading to the latest version of the default linux kernel version, but it does not help.

**uname:** `Linux D9-U 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu`

I see fairly often people come across audio problems with AMD cards, but I am unsure about how to proceed. Please, do not hesitate to ask for more information about my system should you require it to help me solve the problem.